# How is the expression "(a/b)*b + a%b - a" always zero in C for non-zero 'b'?

Tags: c, type-conversion, expression, division, modulo

The following is an excerpt from the C book by Mike Banahan & Brady [(Link: Section 2.8.2.1)](http://publications.gbdirect.co.uk/c_book/chapter2/expressions_and_arithmetic.html). A pleb like me has no reason to doubt that the author is wrong, unless you folks suggest otherwise.

Please tell me how on earth **"(a/b)*b + a%b - a"** is always zero for integers where b is not zero.

Extracted text follows:

> If either operand is negative, the result of / may be the nearest
>   integer to the true result on either side, and the sign of the result
>   of % may be positive or negative. Both of these features are
>   implementation defined.
>
> It is always true that the following expression is equal to zero:
>
> ```
>     (a/b)*b + a%b - a
> ```
>
> unless b is zero.
>
> The usual arithmetic conversions are applied to both of the operands.

Comment: As a note, it was implementation-defined in C89. Since C99, division is defined as rounding towards 0 (and the given equation still holds).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is true by definition of the `%` operator in C.

The definition of the remainder operator in the C Standard says:

> (C11, 6.5.5p6) "If the quotient a/b is representable, the expression (a/b)*b + a%b shall equal a;"

Also note that for both `/` and `%`, if the second operand is `0` the Standard specifies the operation to be undefined behavior.

Comment: Hmmnn....answers it....all meat..I am trying to chew...it will take a while to digest.. +1.

Comment: I never expected this example could be in standard :O

Comment: @haccks Wait a minute...did I just inadvertently mention an expression from the standard in my question? :-)

Comment: @haccks Can you please look into what I have asked in the second update in the question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25960878/how-possibly-can-a-unary-operator-cause-integral-promotion-in-a-or-a/25960900#25960900

Answer (score 4):

Mathematically...

On paper, (a/b)*b == a (b cancels) which is why the result looks funny.

However, the computer first computes (a/b), and then multiplies by b. If this is done in integer arithmetic, then a/b is potentially rounded down before the multiplication.

If a < b, then the result of a/b is 0 , and a%b is a, giving 0 + a - a == 0

if a > b, then (a/b)*b == floor(a/b) and (a/b)*b + a%b == a, again giving 0.

Essentially this is a test of whether the compiler is correctly performing integer arithmetic

Comment: +1. Yeah, a mathematical explanation throws more light on it.

Comment: Sometimes a problem with `a == INT_MIN` and `b == -1`.

Answer (score 2):

If num1/num2 gives quotient q and remainder r, 
then `num1 = q*num2 + r`

Here taking `num1` as `a` and `num2` as `b,`
then `a/b` is the quotient part  and remainder part is `a%b`.

So `a=(a/b)*b+(a%b)` and  **(a/b)*b+(a%b)-a** is equal to **0**